# How to export tracks from QGIS to GPX format including elevation stored in elevation layer created from many hgt files?

Tags: qgis

I have many, many, many GPX files (without elevation) imported to QGIS. 
I did some operations on them.
I imported hgt files with elevation data.
And I want to export those files from QGIS BUT with included elevation data for each lat,lon points. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the QGIS native algorithm 'drape'. It extracts Z values for every vertex from a raster.

If you have lots of separate rasters you might want to combine them first using either GDAL's 'Build virtual raster' or 'Merge' algorithms.

Comment: perfect. You saved a thousands of hours of computations ! I owe you a beer.